# Microsoft teams power virtual agents image

Tags: microsoft-teams, chatbot, power-virtual-agents

I want to use the Power Virtual Agents bot in Microsoft Teams to show a simple guided image.
After publishing, it's showing up on the demo website, but the
but the image is not showing up in the Teams app.

Could you give me any suggestions as to why this might be?

[demo web site image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9frDq.png)
[teams app image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hFiS.png)

- Run multiple reposts
- Same with open URLs that don't require access

Representing images

Comment: Are you sending the image as part of adaptive card? If yes, could you please try upgrading the adaptive card version and check if it helps?